# Does Progress Quest end?

Tags: progress-quest

Are there a fixed number of Acts? I'm assuming at some point I'll reach the limit of whatever armour/item/quest descriptions the developer wrote, but is there any kind of end or ending to Progress Quest?

Comment: You'd think once you've stolen pants from the Yakuza you'd be set for life, but apparently not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no end.

The acts just keep going up in number.
The quest descriptions are randomly generated (eventually you would generate repeats),.
Armor/items also are randomly generated and have a bonus (+X) that starts getting added pretty early on.

The only thing that really "ends" the game is that the next level would take longer to reach than you will live (in real life).

Comment: I'm sure the game will end (or at least crash) once it runs out of space to store its numbers. If the dev used an unsigned int, that would mean that there can be as many as 4,294,967,295 acts. Happy gaming :)

Comment: Well, the source code for the game was released some time back. You could see if that will cause a crash or if it will simply overflow and go back to 0 but still continue on. In any case, you'd probably die before getting to that point.

Comment: I looked at the code, but you beat me to the answer. :) I can't find any obvious check for a natural "ending" of a character, it will go until the storage for its various stats overflows (mostly 32-bit numbers). Then it will start to act oddly and probably eventually crash; this is in fact mentioned in the [FAQ](http://progressquest.com/faq.php).